# Recurring Function with Matrix Input

Tags: matlab

I believe most functions in MATLAB should be able to receive matrix input and return the output in the form of matrix.

For example sqrt([1 4 9]) would return [1 2 3].

However, when I tried this recurring factorial function:

```
function k = fact(z)
if z ~= 0
    k = z * fact(z-1);
else
    k = 1;
end

end
```

It works perfectly when a number is input into fact. However, when a matrix is input into fact, it returns the matrix itself, without performing the factorial function.

E.g.

fact(3) returns 6
fact([1 2 3]) returns [1 2 3] instead of [1 2 6].

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Think you need a loop, because with `z ~= 0` you are comparing the whole matrix and I think to satisfy that you need all of the elements of `z` satisfying it.

Comment: Though you said the changes worked for you, but I guess it would be nice not to keep this question unanswered (or unaccepted if that's the correct term). So, maybe post your own solution and accept it or choose the best one from the ones already presented here and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MATLAB is not known to be good with recursive functions, how about a vectorized approach? Try this for a vector input -

```
mat1 =  repmat([1:max(z)],[numel(z) 1])
mat1(bsxfun(@gt,1:max(z),z'))=1
output1 = prod(mat1,2)
```

Sample run -

```
z =
     1     2     7
output1 =
           1
           2
        5040
```

---

For the sake of answering your original question, here's the annoying loopy code for a vector or 2D matrix as input -

```
function k1 = fact1(z1)

k1 = zeros(size(z1));
for ii = 1:size(z1,1)
    for jj = 1:size(z1,2)
        z = z1(ii,jj);
        if z ~= 0
            k1(ii,jj) = z .* fact1(z-1);
        else
            k1(ii,jj) = 1;
        end
    end
end

return
```

Sample run -

```
>> fact1([1 2 7;3 2 1])
ans =
           1           2        5040
           6           2           1
```

Comment: Your previous comment worked as well :) I added a for i=1:numel(z) loop and replaced all instances of z and k with z(i) and k(i). This sample code looks rather advanced for my stage but thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`gamma`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html) function to compute the factorial without recursion:

```
function k = fact(z)
k = gamma(z+1);
```

Example:

```
>> fact([1 2 3 4])
ans =
     1     2     6    24
```

Comment: Interesting function! Has to work for factorial case! +1

Comment: @Divakar In fact, the Gamma function is [arguably the most meaningful extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of the factorial for non-integer values

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if all of you know, but there is an actual [`factorial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html) function defined in MATLAB that can take in arrays / matrices of any size, and computes the factorial element-wise.  For example:

```
k = factorial([1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8])

k =

           1           2           6          24
         120         720        5040       40320
```

---

Even though this post is looking for a recursive implementation, and Divakar has provided a solution, I'd still like to put my two cents in and suggest an alternative.  Also, let's say that we don't have access to `factorial`, and we want to compute this from first principles.  What I would personally do is create a cell array that's the same size as the input matrix, but each element in this cell array would be a linear index array from `1` up to the number defined for each location in the original matrix.  You would then apply [`prod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) to each cell element to compute the factorial.  A precondition is that no number is less than 1, and that all elements are integers.  As such:

```
z1 = ... ; %// Define input matrix here
z1_matr = arrayfun(@(x) 1:x, z1, 'uni', 0);
out = cellfun(@prod, z1_matr);
```

If `z1 = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];`, from my previous example, we get the same output with the above code:

```
out =

       1           2           6          24
     120         720        5040       40320
```

---

This will obviously be slower as there is an `arrayfun` then `cellfun` call immediately after, but I figured I'd add another method for the sake of just adding in another method :)  Not sure how constructive this is, but I figured I'd add my own method and join Divakar and Luis Mendo :)

Comment: I guess OP doesn't have access to the actual factorial function, well somehow he/she doesn't, because that would be too stupid otherwise ;) Your approach works too! +1